# Stop counting when empty row is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in which in one cell I display the sum of other cells `=SUM(I57: I67)`. When I copy
the row containing this formula, it is not adapted, is calculated the whole amount for
the next 10 rows. 
How to adjust the formula to calculate the sum of the values from cells until empty cell?

So in cell `N46` the formula is `=SUM (I46:I56)`
As I copied the rows 46, 47 and 48 the formula of cell `N57` is `=SUM (I57:I67)`

[image]

Comment: Hi, please can you explain better your problem?

Comment: Hey! I want to put in cell N46 the sum of cells I46:I56. Afterwards if i copy the rows 46-49 in coresponding cell to have the sum of I(no.of inserted row): I(no. of inserted row +2).  Or to have a formula in cell N46 where the sum to be calculated until the empty I cell (in my case I56). I hope it is much clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following array formula:

```
{=SUM(A1:INDEX(A1:$A$10000,MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:$A$10000),0)))}
```

For an array end address (i.e $A$10000) you can use any address larger than the last cell used.

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]